# How to do a recursive problem in python Hex To Decimal?

Tags: python, recursion

Hello so i will ask if how to do a recursive function in HexToDec. I don't know what to do man. It didn't get the right answer.

```
def is_valid_input(x):

if x==1 or x==2:
    return True
else:
    return False

 def equiv_decdigits(digit):

equiv_digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A' , 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
for i in range(len(equiv_digits)):
    if digit == equiv_digits[i]:
        return i
    
def hexToDecimal(hex):

decimal = ""
    
decimal_num = 0
power = 0

if hex == 0:
    return 0
else:
    for digit in range(len(hex), 0, -1):
        decimal_num = decimal_num + 16 ** power
        equiv_hex_digit = equiv_decdigits(hex[digit-1])
        power += 1
    return (int(decimal_num) * equiv_hex_digit)


def decimalToHex(decimal):


hexadecimal = []

equiv_digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A' , 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 
'F'] 
if decimal == 0:
    return ""
else:
    first_half, second_half = decimal//16, decimal%16
    return decimalToHex(first_half)+equiv_digits[second_half]


 if _name_ == "_main_":
x = int(input(
    "Enter (1) to convert from decimal to hex, (2) to convert from hex to decimal: "))
print(x)

while not is_valid_input(x):
    print("Invalid input.")
    x = int(input(
        "Enter (1) to convert from decimal to hex, (2) to convert from hex to decimal: "))
    print(x)
if x <= 1:
    # TODO: Ask and print decimal input, convert using decimalToHex(), print decimal 
    equivalent
    decimal = int(input("Enter a decimal value: "))
    print(decimal)
    print("The hexadecimal equivalent of {} is {}.".format(decimal, decimalToHex(decimal)))
elif x == 2:
    # TODO: Ask and print hex input, convert using hexToDecimal(), print hex equivalent
    hex = str(input("Enter a hexadecimal value: "))
    print(hex)
    print("The decimal equivalent of {} is {}.".format(hex, hexToDecimal(hex)))
else:
    print("Invalid input.")
```

I will do a recursive in HexToDec but i can't do it, i don't know what to do. How can i do a recursive in HexToDec? Where can i learn recursive function in HexToDec function.

Comment: Can you please reformat your program code to have valid indentation? As it is it is not possible to follow.

Comment: Actually the code above is correct but it need to be recursive but i can't do the recursive one HexToDec

Comment: Please, pasting the code as is into a file and try to run it will result in various indentation errors.

Comment: How can i post a latest code here? i already fix the indention

Comment: Just edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

To implement recursion you need to determine the base case which is the stopping condition and the step to repeat in order to get to that condition.

### Decimal to Hex

I'll begin with this because it's easier to wrap the mind around.

```
digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A' , 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

If the value is less than 16 then return the equivalent Hex value.

```
if (value < 16):
    return digits[value]
```

If the value is larger then we need to perform another operation to build the Hex string. The modulus `%` and integer division `//` operators are our friends here. Modulus allows us to determine the Hex value to be appended to the final result. The integer division divides the value by 16 and the result is used in the next iteration of the function.

```
return recursive_func_call( value // 16 ) + digits[ value % 16 ]
```

Putting the two parts together gives the complete code for a recursive solution:

```
def dec_to_hex(value):
    digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A' , 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
    if (value < 16):
        return digits[value]
    else:
        return dec_to_hex( value // 16 ) + digits[ value % 16 ]
```

### Hex to Decimal

Now we can use the knowledge gained previously to build the solution because it's simply the reverse process. It seems more complex but it's not really.

Let's start with the base case, if the string is only one character then we just have to return the decimal value. A Dict will be an appropriate data structure for this operation.

```
values = {
    '0': 0, 
    '1': 1,
    '2': 2,
    '3': 3,
    '4': 4,
    '5': 5,
    '6': 6,
    '7': 7,
    '8': 8,
    '9': 9,
    'A': 10,
    'B': 11,
    'C': 12,
    'D': 13,
    'E': 14,
    'F': 15
}
if len(hex_string) == 1:
    return values[hex_string]
```

To convert from Decimal to Hex we had to perform an integer division operation. To do the reverse we will need to perform a multiplication operation and the strength of that multiplication is determined by the length of the string. This insight is key to creating the second case for the recursive function. Here are some examples to guide the process.

```
'F' : values['F'] -> 15
'10' : (values['1'] * 16) + values['0'] -> (1 * 16) + 0 -> 16
'100' : (values['1'] * 16 * 16) + (values['0'] * 16) + values['0'] -> 256
```

The power to apply to 16 is determined by the length of the string and we were already using the string length in the base case. We can create a variable for the power and amend the base case to use it.

```
power = len(hex_string) - 1
if (power == 0):
    return values[hex_string]
```

Now we just need to apply the power of 16 to the value of the character at the front of the string and add the result to that of the function applied to the remainder of the string.

```
return recursive_func_call(hex_string[1:]) + (values[hex_string[0]] * (16 ** power))
```

Again we combine the two elements to create the recursive function.

```
def hex_to_dec(hex_string):
    values = {
        '0': 0, 
        '1': 1,
        '2': 2,
        '3': 3,
        '4': 4,
        '5': 5,
        '6': 6,
        '7': 7,
        '8': 8,
        '9': 9,
        'A': 10,
        'B': 11,
        'C': 12,
        'D': 13,
        'E': 14,
        'F': 15
    }
    power = len(hex_string) - 1
    if (power == 0):
        return values[hex_string]
    else:
        return hex_to_dec(hex_string[1:]) + (values[hex_string[0]] * (16 ** power))
```

Hopefully this walk through of the process is sufficient insight on how to simplify recursion.

Sample code:

```
hex_256 = dec_to_hex(256)
print(hex_256) # "100"
print(hex_to_dec(hex_256)) # "256"
```

Comment: Im going to try this one! thanks!

Comment: i tried it but ot didn't have an output.

Comment: What input did you use in the function calls?

Comment: Actually it is correct. I just forgot to apply some of the data i need to be use. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can accept the answer by toggling the greyed out check mark beside it. Welcome to Stackoverflow! More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers